# this.props.children is undefined in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, children

I am working with ReactJS and I am trying to get the children from `this.props.children` however, it is returning undefined. [According to the documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html) I should have access to this special property.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    console.log("this",this) // this ReactCompositeComponent.createClass.Constructor 
    this.setMenuListeners.apply(this);
    this.loadMenuFromServer();
},

setMenuListeners: function() {
    pubSub.on('mainMenu.menuItemClicked',function() {
        console.log(this.props.children) // undefined
    }.bind(this))
},
```

And here is some of the code that is rendering the children:

```
loadMenuFromServer: function() {
    var menus = []
    $.getJSON(APPFS.menuItems,function(data){
        for(var s in data) {
            menus.push(<MenuItem expandable={true} content={s} />)
            menus.push(<ul onClick={this.menuItemClicked} className="main-menu-submenu">{
                this.loopAndAddMenu(data[s]).map(function(result){
                    return(result)
                })
            }</ul>)
        }
        this.setState({data:menus})
    }.bind(this));
},

loopAndAddMenu: function(data) {
    var menus = []
    for(var s in data) {
        menus.push(<MenuItem expandable={false} content={s} key={data[s]} />)
    }
    return menus
},

render: function(){
    return (
        <ul className="main-menu">
            {this.state.data}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

Comment: It is not apparent from you code if you are sending any children to your component? `<Component>I am a child</Component>`

Comment: @nilgun Edited to show that it should have `children`.

Comment: `this.props.chilren` supposed to contain children sent from parent component. So you should paste the code for the parent component that creates this component.

Comment: In the docs it says: 
> Parent can read its children by accessing the special `this.props.children prop.` http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html. So I am just trying to access the children from the parent. Where does it say that it contains the children sent from the parent component?

Comment: The docs say you can access `Child` component from within `Parent` component via `this.props.children`. `Parent` component has its own `render` method and it can create whatever elements it wants inside it. Inside `Parent` component `this.props.children` will point to `Child` component, not the elements `Parent` component creates itself.

Comment: There is a very good answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20899762/4721085